# Group SQL Server results by similar date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a project that requires me to match medical procedures in a SQL Server database with a corresponding result. EX: procedure note contains `screening` and result note appears within a week of that procedure containing `abnormal`.

The problem is both the procedure notes and the result come into the database as just text in the same table, the only linking information they have is a patient ID. I need to end up with a list of patient ID and date for each matching procedure/result.

I thought about first sorting all text-match procedures and text-match results to separate temporary tables then joining them somehow, but I am not sure how that would work to group by 'within a week of each other' and discard the left overs.

Any tips? Any information that would help answer from here?

Requested additional info:

Basically I have this:

```
PatientID       ReportType       ReportDate     ReportText

24734           Procedure        1/1/1901       Lots O HTML
24734           Report           1/2/1901       Lots O HTML
...
```

This table is the result of already filtering for the words 'screening' and 'abnormal' in the ReportText column.  So given the two results above we can see the Patient ID matches, and there is one of each report type within a week of each other so they should be a match and listed as one line item.

Comment: I'm having trouble following quite what you're wanting to do. If you have any code you could upload to help clear up some confusion that would be great.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the tables you are using?  It is also helpful if you can provide examples of data and results.

Comment: So basically you need to group by ID and list all dates for that ID? eg: 12345, "01-01-2012 02-02-2012"

Comment: If all your data comes in human formatted text than I think you should consider either giving up now, or trying to find or write very sophisticated configurable human input parser. I looked at writing one some years ago (stopped at defining requirements and interfaces), unfortunately never had enough time to complete it.  
There are so many different formats that humans will understand instinctively and you will have to define and parse them all. Yet another question that may help a little - are the records date stamped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do the following

```
select   * 
from     tableA a1
         inner join tableA a2
           on  a1.patientid = a2.patientid
           and a2.textvaluecolumn = 'abnormal'
where    a1.textvaluecolumn = 'screening'
and      datediff(wk, a1.date, a2.date) = 1
```

So you join the same table on patientid, where the left table has the screening part and the right table the abnormal part. Later, you will get some dates, which you can substract from each other with the datediff function, which returns the amount of weeks (wk) difference between the start and end.
You can also use days (d) for that :)

Comment: needed <= in the datediff line, but otherwise seems to work, Thanks!

Comment: Nice, glad i could be of any help :)

Answer (score 0):

what happens when data is like:

```
patientID    text        date 
1            procedure1   1/1/12 
1            procedure2   1/2/12 
2            procedure1   1/5/12 
2            result1      1/12/12 
1            result2      1/8/12 
1            result1      1/9/12
```

how do you know the result text actually matches the procedure?

Comment: That's where the within a week of each other comes in.  Really you don't have any identifier connecting the procedure to the result other than the result will always come in between 0-7 days after the procedure.  That and two screening procedures will never show up within about 6 months of each other.